# Passing data between v-for divs - vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm learning VueJS. This code isn't pretty but it works almost like it should do. My problem is that the API has the title and the href in two separate `v-for` loops, although each one only has one item in it (0). I would like to be able to put the title in the `<img>` alt tags, and I would also like to wrap the image in a `<a>` tag that contains another variable. I don't believe I can declare variables in `{{ }}`. Is there another way I can make a temporary variable that I can use outside of each `v-for`? Or, is this a bad way to approach this problem?

app.js...

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        results : []
    },
    methods: {
        getItems: function () {
            if (this.txtInput && this.mediaType) {
                axios.get("https://www.api.org/search?q="+this.txtInput+"&media_type="+this.mediaType)
                    .then(response  => this.results = response.data);
                this.mediaType = null;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then, my HTML has this...

```
            <div id="app">
                <input id="txtName" v-on:keyup.enter="getItems" v-model="txtInput" type="text"><br>
                <input type="radio" id="image" value="image" v-model="mediaType">
                <label for="image">Image</label>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" id="audio" value="audio" v-model="mediaType">
                <label for="audio">Audio</label>
                <div v-for="result in results">
                        <div v-for="item in result.items">
                            <div v-for="data in item.data">
                                @{{ data.title }}<br>
                            </div>
                            <div v-for="link in item.links">
                                <img v-bind:src="link.href">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I think you have to transform your response data to include a `title` property in each link of each item.

Comment: Ok, thank you. How do I do this?

Comment: @sdexp By writing code

Comment: If you show us what your axios response data looks like, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the indices `data` and `links` in `result.items` belong to one element.
E.g. `result.items.data[0].title` is the title for `result.items.links[0].href`.
Then you can go and declare in the v-for an index:

```
<div v-for="item in result.items">
  <div v-for="(data, index) in item.data">
    @{{ data.title }}<br>
    <img v-bind:src="item.links[index].href">
  </div>
</div>
```

However a much cleaner way is, as stated in the comments to transform your response, using a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties).